# How to let QTcpsocket remain connection after closing DialogWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

In my Qt application, I have a `MainWindow` and a `DialogWindow`. The `DialogWindow` is for setting up server's IP address and port. While `MainWindow` is for performing communication after successful connection.

However, setting up  `QTcpSocket *socket` in `DialogWindow` means that when I close `DialogWindow`, the `socket` will be destroyed, thus the `socket` will be disconnected with the server.

I would like to keep the socket connected to the server after the `DialogWindow` was closed. Are there any methods that can achieve this result？

Please give me some comments and ideas on this. I am quite a newbie to Qt.

DialogSetup.cpp

```
DialogSetup::DialogSetup(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogSetup)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(wasconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(wasdisconnected()));
}
DialogSetup::~DialogSetup()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DialogSetup::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
    m_strIPAdd = ui->lineEditIPAdd->text();
    m_strPort = ui->lineEditPort->text().toInt();

    socket->connectToHost(m_strIPAdd,m_strPort);

    if(!socket->waitForConnected(10000))
    {
       ui->labelStatus->setText("Error");
       QMessageBox::information(this,"Error",socket->errorString());
    }
}
void DialogSetup::wasconnected()
{
    socket->write("Hello server!");
    ui->labelStatus->setText("Connected!");
    ui->pushButtonDisconnect->setDisabled(false);
}

void DialogSetup::wasdisconnected()
{
    ui->labelStatus->setText("Disonnected!");
}

void DialogSetup::on_pushButtonDisconnect_clicked()
{
    socket->close();
}
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSetup_triggered()
{
    dialogsetup = new DialogSetup(this);
    dialogsetup->show();
}
```

Comment: You can place socket pointer in MainWindow class and communicate with socket's signals throuhg DialogSetup form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the socket outside the dialog class. Something like that:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSetup_triggered()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this); //declared as private in MainWindow
    dialogsetup = new DialogSetup(socket, this);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()), dialogsetup, SLOT(wasconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()), dialogsetup ,SLOT(wasdisconnected()));
    dialogsetup->show();
}
```

The dialog class stores a pointer to the socket and operates with it:

```
DialogSetup::DialogSetup(QTcpSocket *socket, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    socket_(socket),
    ui(new Ui::DialogSetup)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

DialogSetup::~DialogSetup()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DialogSetup::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
    m_strIPAdd = ui->lineEditIPAdd->text();
    m_strPort = ui->lineEditPort->text().toInt();

    socket_->connectToHost(m_strIPAdd,m_strPort);

    if(!socket_->waitForConnected(10000))
    {
       ui->labelStatus->setText("Error");
       QMessageBox::information(this,"Error",socket->errorString());
    }
}
void DialogSetup::wasconnected()
{
    socket_->write("Hello server!");
    ui->labelStatus->setText("Connected!");
    ui->pushButtonDisconnect->setDisabled(false);
}

void DialogSetup::wasdisconnected()
{
    ui->labelStatus->setText("Disonnected!");
}

void DialogSetup::on_pushButtonDisconnect_clicked()
{
    socket_->close();
}
```

Comment: Need store one more pointer to this socket in DialogSetup to provide opportunity clicked on button at DialogSetup

Comment: Thanks for you guys help! @t3ft3l--i , do you mean there will be 2 pointers, 1 for the Dialog Setup and 1 for the mainwindow? And may I know what is opportunity clicked on button?

Comment: @Ryan presence`void DialogSetup::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()` so i see you have `QPushButton` and some actions with `socket_` at this slot. So need have access to `socket_` at `DiaglogSetup`. Thats why i said about storing one more pointer to socket: 1 for the `Dialog Setup` and 1 for the `MainWindow`. Or make more complex slot-signal communication between this classes.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i @Cits   I have trouble understanding pointers that used between class. So is `socket_`  a pointer declared in DialogSetup. And I got this `error: C2065: 'socket_' : undeclared identifier`, does it mean I need to declare the `socket_` pointer in DialogSetup?  Also, does this `socket_(socket) `means the class DialogSetup has a socket pointer? Thanks much~~!

Comment: @Ryan yes, you need a declare at `DialogSetup.h` file `QTcpSocket *socket_`

Comment: Yeah, its like  t3ft3l said

Answer (score 0):

Change it's parent, or remove parent at all (though, you'll have to delete socket manually).

But, a better solution would be - not to create socket in dialog, but to pass it there:

```
DialogSetup::DialogSetup(QTcpSocket *socket_, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogSetup),
    socket(socket_)
```

...

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSetup_triggered()
{
    dialogsetup = new DialogSetup(socket, this);
    dialogsetup->show();
}
```

Comment: You can't defined Constructor with parameters `DialogSetup(QObject *parent = 0, QTcpSocket *socket)`, change parameters orders.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i forgot about header - my bad. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! However, I have this error  `error: C2511: 'DialogSetup::DialogSetup(QTcpSocket *,QWidget *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'DialogSetup' ` . , does this means I need to add something to the declaration? I have tried public  QTcpSocket 
`class DialogSetup : public QDialog, public QTcpSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT`, 
but also got errors.

Comment: @Ryan in `DialogSetup.h` you need to change `DialogSetup` constructor's definition to `explicit DialogSetup(QTcpSocket *socket, QWidget *parent = 0);`